# Show the all Events of Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I want to make a Facebook application. In which I made a button. I want when we click on the button then we can show the all events through Facebook sdk. In this we want to show the creted events and birthday also.

please Provie me a sample code for this. I know this question is not good. But I need the help in this. Because I am new in Android.

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/events", new EventRequestListener());

private class EventRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        try {
            // process the response here: executed in background thread
            Log.d("response", "Response: " + response.toString());
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray d = json.getJSONArray("data");

        // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
        // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
        // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
        // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("json", "JSON Error in response");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}
    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,Object state) {}
    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,Object state) {}
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
}
```

Now just parse that response.

Comment: I already do this. But I want to be all data like current Event and the current Birthday of my friends.